# A Jewish Equivalent for this Quote?

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, quotations

I have read an Islamic quote that I like very much: "All praise is due to Allah; all the mistakes have been mine."

Can anyone think of a Jewish source that expresses a similar concept?

Comment: Down votes without reasons . . . great.

Comment: Mike, re "Down votes without reasons", see http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/146, especially: "down-voting is simply that the reader did not find the answer 'useful' - this doesn't necessarily indicate a problem that needs to be stated in a comment". The down-arrow on questions, too, has "not useful" as a reason in the tooltip. I can see why people would say that about this Q (though I didn't vote on it myself): it states no use for the info it seeks except comparative religion ("Islamic quote") and your own personal preference ("I like"), and people probably don't find those two useful.

Comment: I understood that Mike was asking for a Torah source for a nice concept that he had read so that he could "like" and quote the Torah source instead of a non-Torah source, and thus the question is very useful and lovable, and should be upvoted wholeheartedly!

Comment: @msh210 I think I understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The Rock, His work is perfect; for all His ways are justice; a God of faithfulness and without iniquity, righteous and just is He. Is corruption His? No; His children's is the blemish" - Deuteronomy 32:4

Comment: Where did you get this translation from? Is it your own?

Answer (score 10):

The posuk in [Nechemiah 9:33](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16516#v=33) says the same thing:

וְאַתָּה צַדִּיק עַל כָּל-הַבָּא עָלֵינוּ:  כִּי-אֱמֶת עָשִׂיתָ וַאֲנַחְנוּ הִרְשָׁעְנוּ.‏

"You are just in all that has come upon us; for You have dealt truly and we have done wickedly."

Also Pharaoh proclaimed in [Shemos 9:27](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9870#v=27):

ה' הַצַּדִּיק וַאֲנִי וְעַמִּי הָרְשָׁעִים.‏

"The Lord is the righteous One, and I and my people are the guilty ones."

Comment: Pharoah was expressing a specific admission of guilt; not saying that all mistakes ever are from him

Comment: @Michoel, true. "All the mistakes" can mean a specific set of mistakes, too, though. (As opposed to "all mistakes", which can't easily.)